# MapRoute for overload Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this Controller :

```
public class ProfileController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index( long? userkey )
    {
        ...
    }

    public ActionResult Index( string username )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

how can i define MapRoute for this actions work like this:

> mysite.com/Profile/8293378324043043840

this  must be go to first action

> mysite.com/Profile/MyUserName

this  must be go to second action

I have this route for the first action

```
routes.MapRoute( name: "Profile" , url: "Profile/{userkey}" , defaults: new { controller = "Profile" , action = "Index" } );
```

do i need add another MapRoute ? or can i change the current MapRoute for both action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you cannot overload controller actions if you are using the same Http Verb (in your case GET) because you need to have unique action names.

So you need to name your actions differently:

```
public class ProfileController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult IndexKey( long? userkey )
    {
        ...
    }

    public ActionResult IndexName( string username )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or you can use the `ActionNameAttribute` to give different names to your actions:

```
public class ProfileController : Controller
{
    [ActionName("IndexKey")]
    public ActionResult Index( long? userkey )
    {
        ...
    }

    [ActionName("IndexName")]
    public ActionResult Index( string username )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you will need two routes with [using route constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#adding_constraints_to_routes) on the `userkey` to be a numeric value to setup your actions:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Profile", url: "Profile/{userkey}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "IndexKey" },
                constraints: new { userkey = @"\d*"});

routes.MapRoute(name: "ProfileName", url: "Profile/{userName}",
                defaults: new {controller = "Profile", action = "IndexName"});
```

Comment: can you add some **ActionNameAttribute** sample too?

Comment: another question : do i need create separate .cshtml file for each action?

Comment: @Raika not necessarily. You can specify the same view name in both actions: so you can create one index.cshtml and both action should `return View("Index");`